# android:capitalize is not capitalising turkis characters.

Tags: android, uppercase, capitalize

I have an edittext and I need to capitalize all characters I entered to the edittext but Its not changing the turkish characters to uppercase. The Characters not working are i-->İ ş-->Ş ğ-->Ğ ü-->Ü ö-->Ö

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etUserName"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:hint="@string/entrance_username"
android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
android:capitalize="characters"/>
```

Can u help me about that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capitalize, give `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` a try. Check it at the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etUserName"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:hint="@string/entrance_username"
android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Turkish characters.